# Change from tri-boot to dual-boot

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot

I have been tri-booting Windows 7, Windows 8 Release Candidate and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for a few months now. I have decided that, since I have no touch screen, I will not purchase Win 8. I now want to get rid of the Win 8 RC, then add that partition space to my Ubuntu partition, but have no idea how to accomplish this.

Do I need to uninstall Win 8 RC from within Windows first? The grub loader sends me to the Win 8 loader, where I have Win 7 as the default. Does that complicate things?

Any assistance anyone can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Once you have removed a Windows installation, you can run bash terminal and type on the command line: `sudo update-grub` to generate a new grub menu, without the deleted Windows.  This command searches for existing installations and regenerates the menu config file.

Answer (score 1):

First, **backup all of your data before you lose everything you ever loved and cared about.** Then, proceed.

1. Install `gparted` via `sudo apt-get install gparted` or find it in the Software Center. GParted is a [WMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_of_mass_destruction) for filesystems.
2. Open up `gparted` from the menu or start it in a terminal, whichever is your preference.
3. In GParted, find your Windows volume. It should be of format NTFS and will look something like this:

   [image: gparted]
4. Right click on it, and click remove.
5. Hit the check box up near the top or "Edit > Apply All Operations..."

You have now destroyed Windows. Cheers.

Next, let's grow your Ubuntu partition. For this, you'll have to boot into a Live CD since you can't perform operations on a mounted filesystem.

1. Boot up into an Ubuntu Live CD.
2. "Try Ubuntu" if prompted, don't install.
3. Install GParted in this Live CD, for this you'll probably need internet access.
4. Find your Ubuntu partition of type `ext4` on your hard disk.
5. Right click then click "Resize/Move."
6. Resize it however large you'd like. If Windows was before it on the disk, ie: you have a large empty space of filesystem space before your Ubuntu partition, you should also move it. This will take time.

   6a. If you're resizing *and* moving, you should do them separately. Do a move before a resize, as a move will take a lot of time. To do this, move the disk without increasing the size, then continue to step 7 below. After that completes (will take a while) proceed to resize the partition to fill your disk.
7. Apply changes.
8. Profit.